# How to make a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I am trying to make a multidimensional array.

```
  $a = array(
        array(
            '1' => 'One',
            '2' => 'two'
        ),
        array(
            '3' => 'three',
            '4' => 'four'
        )
    );

    $query_array = array();
    foreach( $meta_keys as $meta_key ) {
        $query_ = array();
        foreach( $meta_key as $key ) {
            $query_['key1'] = 'val1';
            $query_['key2'] = 'val2';
            $query_['key3'] = $meta_key;    
        }
        array_push( $query_array, $query_ );
    }
```

That is I am trying. But no luck.

I want an array so that it will be as below...

```
 $query_array = array(
    array(
        'key1'  => 'val1',
        'key2'  => 'val2',
        'key3'  => 'one' //only change here
    ),
    array(
        'key1'  => 'val1',
        'key2'  => 'val2',
        'key3'  => 'two' //only change here
    ),
    array(
        'key1'  => 'val1',
        'key2'  => 'val2',
        'key3'  => 'three' //only change here
    )
  // Goes here same until the first $a value is end.
);
```

I have used `array_merge()` and `array_combine()` function with different way in `foreach` loop. But no result. A great messed up result comes.

So how can I do that in php? 
Thanks

Comment: You've changed __both the value and the key__ for _every single_ element in `$c`, but your comment suggests that the only change is in the third element. This is confusing as your expected result doesn't resemble your problem statement at all. Notice that in `$a[0][1]` the value is `"One"`, but in `$c[0]["key3"]` the value is `"one"`. Is this is a typo or the expected result?

Comment: actually I need the `$c` array that contains another array having two value from the `$b` and third one value will be coming from the `$a` value. The new will contain  the array as many as `$a` have values.

Comment: Well, it's not that I didn't understand what you were _trying_ to do. It's that your question shows an expected result that is _inconsistent_ with what you said you expected. Please edit the question such that the expected result more closely resembles this.

Comment: is it doable or not? I need that.If it is not doable then I will think another way.

Comment: Is what doable? The point of my comment is clarify on what your expectations are so that we can determine whether or not they are or aren't doable and how to do them. You haven't clarified your expectations yet since you've failed to answer my question or update the question with the expected result that aligns to your statements.

Comment: For example, the array `$a`, in your question, is made up of two arrays, each containing two values. However, since there _can_ be duplicate keys between those arrays, it remains entirely unclear what your expectation is on how to assign the keys in the resulting array `$c`. So I have no idea what you really expect. This makes this type of question highly undesirable on StackOverflow. Please see [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center to improve your question.

Comment: In your first comment what you have mentioned I need that. The `$c[0]["key3]` will receive the `$a` value `one`, That means `$c[1]['key3'] = 'two'`....goes on

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all. You're just repeating a fragment of a sentence that I stated without actually addressing any of its points. Your question still remains very ambiguous and difficult to answer as it's unclear what you expectations are. How do you arrive a `"key3"`? What happens if there are 3 elements in the second array? Why does `$a[0][1] === "One"` but `$c[0]["key3"] == "one"`? You haven't managed to answer a single one of my questions yet. Sorry, but I vote to close this question as unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121443/discussion-between-chayan-biswas-and-sherif).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work :

```
$res = [];
array_walk_recursive($a, function($item) use ($res, $b){
    $b["key3"] = $item;
    res[] = $b;
});
```

It's untested.